# How to sync and read files from S3 bucket through R Studio - SSH'ed to local host with Putty?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, ssh, rstudio, putty

I am new to AWS, RStudio and SSH, so this may sound trivial but I need desperate help.

I was able to SSH the instance and RStudio by following some resources but now I want to regularly sync and read files from a public S3 bucket. I can get the bucket content and try to read with s3read_using() command but the file is bigger than it supports and I cannot do it.

How can I sync the S3 bucket and read files? Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can aws CLI s3 sync method to sync a bucket with folder

> The sync command is used to sync directories to S3 buckets or prefixes and vice versa. It recursively copies new and updated files from the source ( Directory or Bucket/Prefix ) to the destination ( Directory or Bucket/Prefix ). It only creates folders in the destination if they contain one or more files.

for reference and usage:

https://codedestine.com/aws-s3-sync-command/

Comment: Yes I downloaded  AWSCLI earlier. And on my Putty command screen I can create a directory, change dr to that directory, and use the following to sync:  aws s3 sync 'filename' s3:'bucket_name'/'file_name' it says this directory does not exist when I know it does.

Comment: are you trying to sync folder or just a file ?

Comment: I am trying to sync a folder to be used in my RStudio. I am very confused, the error now says "following arguments are required:paths"

Comment: in the command you mentioned above does not seem correct : it should be aws s3 sync  ./folder/ s3://bucket_name/folder make sure the folder exists in both s3 and local disk

Comment: Please mind my ignorance. I am new to all this. Are these commands supposed to be written on command window that opens when I use PuTTY ?

Comment: you can create a cron job  to sync the folder based on your preference

Comment: Hi. Yes, finally it is working. Apparently I had to do it under Tools -> Shell of RStudio on my localhost after getting AWS configurations in PuTTY SSH. And also, I was typing the wrong command, thanks for correcting it. I copied my files, and I also tried getting/pushing and syncing, it all seems working now.

Comment: sure, glad to help, please upvote for the answer and mark it as resolved